# IE9 Loses Cookie

Tags: session, cookies

I'm using session in my application. When accessing the application using IP address, I can get the cookie successfully. However, if I use domain name or localhost, "sometimes" document.cookie returns empty and I'm not able to retrieve the cookie.

More info: I'm using IE9 in Win7. I checked the following article and not sure what's the cause of the problem in my case.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/08/20/wininet-ie-cookie-internals-faq.aspx

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you could, show some code, which you used to create and read cookie, it will be helpful in order to correctly answer your questions.

Answer (score 2):

Im not sure if you still needing it but one thing I discovered was this after finding out IE was not showing our website right while Firefox and Chrome do show up correct.
[http://www.aspnetresources.com/blog/frames_webforms_and_rejected_cookies](https://web.archive.org/web/20130312093839/http://www.aspnetresources.com/blog/frames_webforms_and_rejected_cookies)

I hope you solved it already and/or someone can read my linked website. 
Its about frames and cookies, but maybe it also means someting with diferent domains and redirection.

So, try looking at your test website from Firefox, if its IE, use the fix from that website

> Instead of creating and uploading privacy policies to your sites, you can serve a “compact policy,” i.e. a “p3p” HTTP header, e.g.: “IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT”. A policy generator can produce one instead of an XML file. In ASP.NET it’s a one-liner that you can put into your page base class or master page:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader (
   "p3p",
   "CP=\"IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi 
        CONi HIS OUR IND CNT\"");
```

its my first post here, hope it will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing a simillar problem - while on chrome,opera,ff,safari session worked well, on IE9 user was randomly logged out while accessing different sites. It came out, that the problem is in setting session on different domains.
Sites where served from X.com, while avatars(throught PHP script-access had to be authorized) from static.X.com. Changing to X.com/static/ helped.